# Python error when trying to use gnuradio/uhd in Windows

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion, usrp, uhd

I am trying to install UHD and gnuradio on Windows. I can't find binary files for gnuradio, it looks like the link to their binary install is broken and the [website](http://www.gcndevelopment.com/gnuradio/downloads.htm) is down. So I used gnuradio in Pothos Project. When I run my grc file in gnuradio, it runs correctly. However when I run it in command prompt I get this error:

```
E:\Alireza\sdr_A20\4channel\recorder>recorder_grc.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Alireza\sdr_A20\4channel\recorder\recorder_grc.py", line 12, in <module>
    from gnuradio import uhd
  File "E:\Program Files\PothosSDR\lib\python2.7\site-packages\gnuradio\uhd\__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    _prepare_uhd_swig()
  File "E:\Program Files\PothosSDR\lib\python2.7\site-packages\gnuradio\uhd\__init__.py", line 38, in _prepare_uhd_swig
    import uhd_swig
  File "E:\Program Files\PothosSDR\lib\python2.7\site-packages\gnuradio\uhd\uhd_swig.py", line 17, in <module>
    _uhd_swig = swig_import_helper()
  File "E:\Program Files\PothosSDR\lib\python2.7\site-packages\gnuradio\uhd\uhd_swig.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_uhd_swig')
  File "E:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named _uhd_swig
```

Anybody knows what can be wrong? I thought it's a path issue but it looks like my PYTHONPATH is pointing to "E:\Program Files\PothosSDR\lib\python2.7\site-packages" which looks correct. I also realized while I can perform `import gnuradio` in python, `import uhd` gives throws an import error. But I am not sure how I can find it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Find where `uhd.dll` and `_uhd_swig.pyd` files are located and add the full directories paths to the `PATH` environment variable.